# Workaround for building oracle_fdw on m1 mac

Tags: postgresql, oracle, postgres-fdw, oracle-fdw

I'm trying to compile [oracle_fdw](https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw#5-installation-requirements) on an m1 mac, of course its not supported yet due to the unavailability of an arm version of [oracle instant client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/macos-intel-x86-downloads.html).

Are there any workarounds for that?

Comment: you could cross compile on the M1 for x86 architecture...

Comment: can you provide a little bit more details? 
have you tried it yourself? have you faced any issues? @p3consulting